# create animation or allow margin to gradually get to point in scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".filter-page").css('margin', '-' + (30 - fromTop) + 'px 0px 0px 0px');
    $(".filter").css('margin', '-' + (5% - fromTop) + 'px 0px 0px 0px'); // changed from 150 to 5%
});
```

The above works when *using non-percentage*. But when I changed '150' to 5% it no longer works. The reason for this attempt is to allow the transition between the number to gradually get to that point. Or to increment. **Currently on page load when at '150' the filter element is automatically -150px on the page, I would like it to gradually get to this point within the scroll function.** Or incorporate an animation between, somehow - while the user is scrolling.

Comment: And what is this code doing exactly? All we read here is your non-working approach, not the problem. If you state the problem, people may suggest an alternative.

Comment: You can always calculate the percentage when you know the scrolled distance and the total height of the scrollable area